# how to send auto delete messages whit Telegram bot

Tags: python, c#, telegram-bot

I have a doubt.  I've been looking for information and haven't found anything.  I would like to know if it is possible to send a message with a bot which will be eliminated after a certain time.  I'm working with c# but I think other examples will work for me.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I thought I would delete my own message after a while but I think it would not be a solution in a well active chat, since there are many messages coming in all the time and I would not know for sure what the id of the message I sent is. I would have to do another algorithm to find out what that id is, and what I was trying to see is if there was some simpler method already implemented in the api for these specific cases. Send messages using the bot with self-destruct after a while.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if telegram API provides that.

but you can implement it in the bot to do that, maybe with "time" or "schedule" in python